# How to calculate predicted burst time?

Tags: operating-system

calculate the predicted burst time if th estimated time is 0.29 ms actual time is .47 ms and weighing parameter is .35.
According to this formula

T(n+1)=tn(p)+(1-p)T(n)

tn=Actual time=.47 ms

p=weighing parameter=.35

T(n+1)=predicted burst time=?

but i am getting a problem

T(n)=T(0)=initial burst time

is estimated time(0.29 ms)=T(0) ?

Comment: you sure the formula is right? isn't itT(n+1)=p*T(n)+(1-p)*T(n)

Comment: its T(n+1)=p*t(n)+(1-p)*T(n)

Comment: @m0s can you tell me what is estimated time?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes! `T(0)=estimated time`. Because S J F (shortest-job-first) estimates the amount of CPU burst time needed by a job in its next CPU burst, based on the time used in the current and past CPU burst times (Breadth First Approach).
So:

```
T(n+1)=p*t(n)+(1-p)*T(n)

tn=Actual time=.47 ms

p=weighing parameter=.35

T(n+1)=predicted burst time=next predicted burst time=?

T(n)=T(0)=initial burst time

estimated time(0.29 ms)=T(0)
```